# LatLng object will NOT work if it is instantiated with double variables, it will only work if fed real numbers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to use the google maps api for a school project.  When I create a LatLng object using two hard-coded numbers the map works great.  When I try and use two double variables it doesn't work?  Help Please I am going insane!

Please believe me that the variables latitude and longitude are assigned to perfectly good doubles that when printed as strings are exactly 33.190802, -117.301805

```
//WORKS PERFECTLY
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        //Specify our location with latlng class
        LatLng myPostition = new LatLng(33.190802, -117.301805);
        //Add our position to the map
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPostition).title("Current Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker)));
        //move camera to our position
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myPostition).zoom(10.0f).build();
        //update the position --> move to the location
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        //instruct the map to move to this position
        map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

//DOSEN'T WORK--But I need latitude and longitude to be set programmatically

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        //Specify our location with latlng class
        LatLng myPostition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //Add our position to the map
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPostition).title("Current Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker)));
        //move camera to our position
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myPostition).zoom(10.0f).build();
        //update the position --> move to the location
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        //instruct the map to move to this position
        map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What are you specific symptoms?

Comment: It doesn't work means the map is set to 0,0 when you try to instantiate the LatLng object with variables assigned 33.190802 and -117.301805, but when hardcoded the addMarker method shows the proper location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not a valid avlue in your vars

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    latitude =  33.190802;
    longitude =  -117.301805; 
    //Specify our location with latlng class
     LatLng myPostition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
       ......
```

could be you need  a way for pass  valid values  to your vars

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap, latitude, longitude) {
       map = googleMap;
       LatLng myPostition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
       ......
```